# Unable to login to Youtube acc through google sign-in with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, chromium

When executing my puppeteer code, I'm unable to get past the email page after clicking next because of some sort of bot protection from Google stating "Try using a different browser...etc". Is there a way to bypass this with puppeteer? I have looked into it and some solutions included not setting useragent and making it non-headless which still doesn't work.

````
// add stealth plugin and use defaults (all evasion techniques)
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())

async function start(){
    var browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        slowMo: 30,
        ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'],
        args: [
           '--window-size=1280,800',
           '--hide-scrollbars',
           '--disable-web-security',
           '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process'
        ],
      })
      var page = (await browser.pages())[0]
      await page.setViewport({
         width: 1280,
         height: 800
       })
    await page.goto('https://www.youtube.com/account');
    await page.type('#identifierId', 'soapy1310@gmail.com');
    await page.click('.VfPpkd-RLmnJb');
   

}

start()```
````

Comment: So, what you're asking is, some site protects against bots, and you want help bypassing that protection so your bot can run?

Comment: You cannot bypass googles bot detection, you'll get permanently banned. I suggest you scrape google with caution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not answer but it may helps you.
YouTube detect bots if you change the viewports so what you have to do first is to add arguments:

```
.DefaultViewport = Nothing,
```

Then:  `"--start-maximized",`

then try to use default webproxy of your interent if you want to use proxies I suggest to you to buy real paid 5G or Wifi mobil proxies.

PS: (You cannot bypass googles bot detection, you'll get permanently banned. I suggest you scrape google with caution) = LOL it is funny answer so many 'bots'out there even they use YouTube API's and secrets and Google knows about it and you says that they will ban him? pls stop posting nonsense, just search Github and look good.